# This function cannot be compiled as managed, consider using #pragma unmanaged

Tags: c++, managed-c++

Here's a function that I have:

```
    static System::Numerics::Complex PushReduce(long nArray1, long nArray2,
        List<System::Tuple<double,System::Numerics::Complex>^>^ array1,
        List<System::Tuple<double, System::Numerics::Complex>^>^ array2)
    {
        std::vector<CudaExports::DataPoint> warray1, warray2;
        warray1.resize(nArray1);
        warray2.resize(nArray2);

        for each(auto v in array1)
        {
            warray1.emplace_back(v->Item1, thrust::complex<CalcType>(v->Item2.Real, v->Item2.Imaginary));
        }
        for each(auto v in array2)
        {
            warray2.emplace_back(v->Item1, thrust::complex<CalcType>(v->Item2.Real, v->Item2.Imaginary));
        }

        auto result= CudaExports::PushReduce(warray1, warray2);


        return System::Numerics::Complex(result.real(), result.imag());
    }
```

It is calling this function:

```
thrust::complex<CalcType> PushReduce(const std::vector<DataPoint>& array1, const std::vector<DataPoint>& array2)
```

The compilation fails with following errors:

```
'cudaProxy::CalculateWithCuda::PushReduce': this function cannot be compiled as managed, consider using #pragma unmanaged
'System::Numerics::Complex cudaProxy::CalculateWithCuda::PushReduce(long,long,System::Collections::Generic::List<System::Tuple<double,System::Numerics::Complex> ^> ^,System::Collections::Generic::List<System::Tuple<double,System::Numerics::Complex> ^> ^)': managed type or function cannot be used in an unmanaged function   cudaProxy   
'cudaProxy::CalculateWithCuda::PushReduce': __clrcall cannot be used on functions compiled to native code
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: I'm almost certain that you meant to use `reserve` instead of `resize` near the top. I don't think that's the problem the compiler is complaining about, though.

Comment: @NTNW yes, thank you!